Name of white lights above truck rear window
2010 Silveraro 1500
There are exterior white lights above the rear window that illuminate when I turn this knob clockwise when the truck is off.
What are those lights called?


I ask because I want to look up those lights to see if there is a way to turn them on without turning on the interior lights (when the truck is off).

These are the cargo lights. At some point, Chevy/GMC trucks came with a separate switch to turn them on. I don't know what year that happened, though. My 2018 Silvy had one, but my 2006 did not. Since your 2010 doesn't, either, I'd expect it to have come around 2014, which I believe is the first year of my truck's body style.
To that end, the only way you'd be able to turn them on/off separately is to wire a switch to the circuit. You'd have to figure out which one it is, but it should be attached to your dome switch. Might even be the same wire for the dome lights.

Thanks! Some related info in this post: https://www.gm-trucks.com/forums/topic/106956-cargo-light/#comment-949261
